# How to do app content presentation in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, user-experience

I am writing here because I can't find any help over the web. I am developing application for Windows Phone that has many links to other pages and some are not that obvious. That's why I would like to present content to the user after she starts application for the first time. I thought about making some page that will have screenshots of app with some tips where user is able to click - but I don't know if it is the right way to do? Maybe you have met with similiar question before? Please let me know if there is better way - or maybe there is even some control for that?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of Apps on the store that present you with an intro on how they work when you launch them the first time.

4Blend HDR would be an example of such an App as would several of the Imaging Apps Nokia provides. I suggest to take a look at those samples to see how they deal with the issue.

I'm not aware of a ready made control for this but to me it looks like separate pages containing Screenshots of the regular UI with explanatory text and a button that does regular page transitions. You would have to store wether or not the intro has already been completed in IsolatedStorage. If it has not you navigate from your Startpage to the first page of the intro page and remove the Startpage from the Backstack (NavigationService).